# How to import vaadin-icon into React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, icons, vaadin

I want to use [`@vaadin/vaadin-icons`](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-icons/tree/master/assets/svg) in my React project.

I'm trying to use:

```
import VaadinPlus from "@vaadin/vaadin-icons/assets/svg/plus.svg";

<ListItemIcon>
  {VaadinPlus}
</ListItemIcon>
```

[Here is the CodeSandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/zljo9pmwp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to import the icons, as given in the [docs](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-icons/install) is

> `import '@vaadin/vaadin-icons/vaadin-icons.js';`

And then, consumption as per [docs](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-icons/html-examples)

> `<iron-icon icon="vaadin:vaadin-h"></iron-icon>`

Following this, I've forked a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/14y0k13mzq). Do check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your webpack to use [react-svg-loader](https://github.com/boopathi/react-svg-loader) it allows you to import SVG icons like JSX components:

```
import Logo from './logo.svg';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <Logo fill="red" className="logo" width={50} height={50} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and minimum config looks like this:

```
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: "babel-loader"
    },
    {
      loader: "react-svg-loader",
      options: {
        jsx: true // true outputs JSX tags
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How would that look in my [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zljo9pmwp) using vaadin icons?

Comment: I'm not familiar with codeSendbox, I don't see the webpack config.